# How to do enabled and disabled button using pure PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am stuck on how to enabled and disabled button in only PHP without using JavaScript, jQuery and other, I am new in PHP programming please help me to find out this situation.
This is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    echo 'Hello robin';
}

if(isset($_POST['serach']))
{
    echo 'Byeeee robin';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container jumbotron">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="btn-group-xs">
                    <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="save">Save</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="btn2" name="serach">Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing: stop that stupid habbit shown in many tutorials to implement a html form and the processing logic inside one script. Use two separate files or scripts. Second: if you did so, then once you click the submit button the form is replaced by whatever html you send as a reply to the form processing (another html page or a redirection), which should answer your question.

Comment: Exactly, what you needed? Disable which button? In what condition it is going to disabled?

Comment: php is server side, so unless you plan to have it disabled from the start, you can't change it unless it's with javascript.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion and help sir

Comment: Fixed code formatting and removed unrelated tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable for example the Save button after a successful save operation like this:

```
<?php
$isSaveDisabled = false;
if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        echo 'Hello robin';
        $isSaveDisabled = true;
    }
if(isset($_POST['serach']))
    {
        echo 'Byeeee robin';
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="container jumbotron">

        <form action="" method="post">

            <div class="btn-group-xs">
            <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="save" <?php if ($isSaveDisabled) { echo 'disabled="disabled"';}?>>Save</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btn2" name="serach">Search</button>
            </div>


        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since PHP is stateless and this basic solution induces a full page rendition each time after an user interaction you have to evaluate and build the state of the whole application and render the page based on it after each request. (In this simple example it only means that you have to evaluate whether Save button is enabled or not.)

You always have to validate the state on back-end side even if you have some front-end logic involved since it's easy to overcome on JS-only restrictions.
However, it usually worth to have both to achieve better user experience (Save button is disabled immediately if save is done via AJAX, the user don't have to wait for a full page reload)

As the gentlemen suggested in the comments it's very important to separate your logic and code as much as possible. If it's just for experimenting, it's completely fine. But as your application grows it becomes harder to know what's happening exponentially. So it can result more and more bugs and hard-to-maintain product.

UPDATE (for the question on disabling Save button after pressing the Creating button.)

This is typically a function what is much better to implement with JavaScript so I don't recommend it for production use. But if you want pure PHP solution you can do it like this:

```
<?php
$isSaveDisabled = false;
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    echo 'Hello robin';
} else if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $isSaveDisabled = true;
}
if(isset($_POST['serach'])) {
    echo 'Byeeee robin';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="container jumbotron">

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="btn-group-xs">
                <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="save" <?php if ($isSaveDisabled) { echo 'disabled="disabled"';}?>>Save</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btn2" name="serach">Search</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btn3" name="create">Create</button>
            </div>
         </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you are moving to implementing complex applications it can help if you learn a template solution like the ol'trusty Smarty: http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: thanks david but i have one more question that i have four buttons like Save, Create, Modify, Delete, now i want to disable Save button on click of Create button please suggest

Comment: Updated the answer. The solution is similar to the previous one but you have to check if the create button was pressed and disable save accordingly.