# how to disable button for single user in php

Tags: php

Can Anyone tell me how to disable button for single(specific) user in php.
I have tried these code but did not work.

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
                                            <input disabled="true" type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->lang->line('text_btn_submit'); ?>" name="social_submit" class="btn btn-primary " <?php
                                                   if ($this->system->demo_user == 1) {
                                                       echo 'disabled';
                                                   }
```

Comment: Do you have a login system or something like this? How can you identify the user identity? Or maybe this is your question... because it is not so comprehensible...

Comment: Just a correction, you're missing closing tag `>` for `<input>`? Remove `disabled="true"`, it should be enabled by **default**, it should disable the button when `$this->system->demo_user == 1` is true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do enabled and disabled button using pure PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084856/how-to-do-enabled-and-disabled-button-using-pure-php)

Comment: Yes I have tried by removing 'disable=true' Also i can see by logging in with demo_user it is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by creating a field in my database with a role.  If the user is a user account, he/she could not access particular link.

Comment: Sir , ho can we do same think in php by inserting some special code ??

Comment: I have a column in my database for role.  If someone is an admin, some links become available to him/her.  If the role is a user role, those links become unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

In oreder to make something for a specific user, you first need to identify the user.
The most common way to do so is by creating a login system.
It means that every time, every user would have to login to your website/app with a username and a password.

In order to make a login system, you need to build a page that gets a username and a password and check if this user exists in your database. You can read more about login system in the internet, and maybe take ideas from others.

Another thing you can do is identify the user with `SESSION`s.
You can read about sessions more in the internet (or ask here a new question) but in general, sessions are variables which are saved on the server, and they are multi-page variables (it means that even if the user go to another page, the variable will still hold its original value).

Therefore, it means that if a user (the specific one you are talking about) do something "special", you can define a `$_SESSION` variable that will hold the value `'thisOne'` and then you can check the session to know if a user is the specific user you want to identify.

Finally,
After making something which can identify the user identity, you can easily make a `disabled` attribue in input tags after writing some `<?php  something-that-checks-the-user-identity  ?>`

Comment: Sir first of all thank for replying. I have all pages already that you have mentioned like login etc. My question is only that how can we disable a specific button for single (specific) user by inserting code.